# where method for Array

Tags: ruby, methods, hash

I am pretty much trying to mimic the class method of `where`, but instead on an instance, this instance being an array of hashes. For example: this exists as a class method `Class.where(:name => "Joe")`, so I want to be able to do this:

```
@joe = {:name => "Joe", :title => "Mr.", :job => "Accountant"}
@kelly = {:name => "Kelly", :title => "Ms.", :job => "Auditor"}
@people = [@joe, @kelly]
```

and call this:

```
@people.where(:name => 'Joe')
```

which should return the `@joe` object.

How should I write this?

Comment: I don't know Rails, but I assume the class method `where` you mention is from `ActiveRecord` (as there is no Ruby method `Array::where`). If so, you should edit so that it reads something like, "...to mimic the class method `Array::where,...` provided by `ActiveRecord`" (but do not add a `Rails` or `ActiveRecord` tag, imo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understood the task, you want to have `Array#where` defined. Here you go:

```
▶ class Array
▷   def where hash
▷     return nil unless hash.is_a? Hash # one might throw ArgumentError here
▷     self.select do |e| 
▷       e.is_a?(Hash) && hash.all? { |k, v| e.key?[k] && e[k] == v }
▷     end 
▷   end  
▷ end  
#⇒ :where
▶ @people.where(:name => 'Joe')
#⇒ [
#  [0] {
#      :job => "Accountant",
#     :name => "Joe",
#    :title => "Mr."
#  }
# ]
▶ @people.where(:name => 'Joe', :job => 'Accountant')
#⇒ [
#  [0] {
#      :job => "Accountant",
#     :name => "Joe",
#    :title => "Mr."
#  }
# ]
▶ @people.where(:name => 'Joe', :job => 'NotAccountant')
#⇒ []
```

Hope it helps.

**UPD** Slightly updated the function to distinguish `nil` values and absent keys. Credits to @CarySwoveland.

Comment: Well done, particularly the addition of "and" functionality! Now you just have to incorporate "or" and "not".

Comment: Perhaps `select { |e| e.is_a?(Hash) && hash.all? { |k, v|  e.key?(k) && e[k] == v } }`, where `e.key?(k)` is to permit the hash to have `nil` values.

Comment: Updated? Where's the "or" and "not" functionality? (You're one of those who favour's unnecessary `self.`'s?)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to retrieve the first element that matches:

```
@people.find     { |p| p[:name] == 'Joe' }
```

or [Enumerable#find_all](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) to retrieve all elements that match:

```
@people.find_all { |p| p[:name] == 'Joe' }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@people.find{|p| p[:name] =='Joe'}
```

or

```
@people.find(:name => 'Joe').first
```

or

```
@people.select{|p| p[:name ]== 'Joe'}.first
```

With a method:

```
def find_user params
  @people.find(params).first
end

find_user name:'Joe'
=> {:name=>"Joe", :title=>"Mr.", :job=>"Accountant"}
```

Comment: I want this method to be versatile, to the "user" can search by either name, title, or job and the method can parse through it acordingly

Comment: im getting `undefined method 'find' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Use `@joe = {:name => "Joe", :title => "Mr.", :job => "Accountant"}
@kelly = {:name => "Kelly", :title => "Ms.", :job => "Auditor"}
@people = [@joe, @kelly]`.

Comment: The error means that `@people` is not defined. Did you put the method within a class?

Comment: yeah, I put it within the Array class

Comment: In that case, `@people` does not exist within the Array class. Use `find(params).first` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit different to Rails' `where`, more like `find_by`: `where` returns a relation, a collection of instances. Actually, the implementations of both are about the same and use different methods of [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html):

```
@people.select { |h| h[:name] == 'Joe' } # where-like
@people.find   { |h| h[:name] == 'Joe' } # find_by-like
```

You can generalize it at any time, by running [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) on conditions hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about an actual array of hashes and not active record:

```
@some_array.select {|item| item["search_key"] = 'search val' }
```